# Using VBA to change system locale

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that uses some Msgbox commands and the messages are in Greek characters. In order to display the messages properly, I have to change the System locale (from regional settings) to "Greek". I want to change the system locale with VBA to "Greek" so that  the macro enabled workbook can work with all machines. Another solution would be that the macro will identify the current system locale and warn the user to change it to "Greek" if it is not before running the macro. How can I do this?

Comment: You should never change a user's settings like this. Your code should adapt to a user's settings, not the other way round - that's just bad practice.

Comment: You do not need to change the System locale for displaing a Greek characters. Use `ChrW()` to add any unicode character to string.

Comment: @omegastripes: This is practically impossible if I want to write many words in greek and not few letters.

Comment: Do that automated, by utility procedure, not manually. Convert strings in a worksheet cells in other locale into ASCII VBA code lines (ChrW, encodeURIComponent, base64, etc.)